# Spring autowire / Java

Tags: java, spring, autowired

If I have two classes like:

```
Class A {
     public String importantValue = "stringvalue";

     @Autowire
     public B b;
}

@Component
@Scope("prototype");
Class B {
     // This should be set automatically
     // from IOC Container upon injection.
     public String importantValueFromA;
}
```

Is this even possible? As soon as B class has been injected to A it should automatically set the value in B.

Comment: I guess your `A` class is also a Spring bean with default (`singleton`) scope? You are missing `@Service` annotation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want class `A` to do some setup on injected class `B`? That's simple:

```
@Service
class A {
    private String importantValue = "stringvalue";

    @Autowire
    private B b;

    @PostConstruct
    public void initB() {
        b.importantValueFromA = this.importantValue;
    }
}
```

Obviously you cannot access `b.importantValueFromA` in `A.A` constructor because injection didn't yet happen. But `@PostConstruct` callback is guaranteed to be called after injection.

Another approach is to use setter injection, but it feels kind of hacky:

```
private B b;

@Autowire
public void setB(B b) {
    this.b = b;
    b.importantValueFromA = this.importantValue;
}
```

Two suggestions:

- keep your fields `private` and use setters/methods to access them.
- injecting prototype scoped bean to singleton bean might have some unexpected results. Enough to say only one instance of `B` will be created.

Comment: Both solutions require that you remember to set the importantValue on B manually :(,

I was hoping that I could by reflection or something get hold of what object has tried to inject the component. So I can do the magic stuff in B ;)

Comment: @user1051218: can you explain your use-case in more detail? You want a callback every time your bean gets injected to any other bean? How you want to use this?

Answer (score 0):

No. B is created before A (since A depends on B) so it will not update the value itself. You have to use a contructor injection:

```
Class A {
     public String importantValue = "stringvalue";

     @Autowire
     public A(B b) {
          b.importantValueFromA = this.importantValue;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about doing something like this:

Declare your class B as a scoped proxy, which underlying will expose a proxy to A instead of the real B and will respect the prototype scope.

```
@Component
@Scope(value="prototype", proxyMode=ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
class B {
```

Then you can inject in an attribute of A in B this way:

```
@Value("#{a.importantValue}")
private String importantValueFromA;
```

Here is a full working example in a gist:

https://gist.github.com/3395329